# Log4j file appender to roll over every X minutes

Tags: java, log4j

How do I configure log4j properties to roll over every X minutes. I know that this can be configured based on size and yearly, monthly, daily basis. With the FileAppender I had wriiten custom code to do this, but it doesnt seem to work.
Please suggest, if anyone has tried this before?

Answer (score 3):

Use DailyRollingFileAppender for the purpose.
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html

Comment: It appears that DailyRollingFileAppender cannot handle minute intervals other than 1 minute. For example every 5 minutes cannot be set.